# NPE in clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod only in some situations

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I'm experiencing a strange problem with Java interop. I wrote a small specialized wrapper around the BDB JE API. When I'm in the repl (cider-repl) everything works fine: I can open the database, add entries, etc. But if I call the add-record function from another function in my app I get an NPE,

```
NullPointerException   clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod (Reflector.java:26)
```

I'm starting to think I'm losing my mind. This opens the database:

```
(defn opendb [envpath dbname]
  (let [envconf (.setAllowCreate (EnvironmentConfig.) true)
        env (Environment. (ensure-directory envpath) envconf)
        dbconf (-> (DatabaseConfig.) (.setAllowCreate true) (.setDeferredWrite true))
        database (.openDatabase env nil dbname dbconf)]
    {:environment env :database database}))
```

Here is `add-record`:

```
(defn add-record [dbm k v]
  (let [key (DatabaseEntry. (.getBytes k "UTF-8"))
        value (DatabaseEntry. (.getBytes v "UTF-8"))]
    (.put (:database dbm) nil key value)))
```

There really isn't anything special going on here. The usage where this yields the NPE is similar to

```
(let [cache (bdb/opendb "local-cache" "subject-map")]
  ;; do stuff
  (doseq [node (function "that returns a sequence of maps")]
    (bdb/add-record cache (:foo node) (:bar node)))
  (bdb/closedb cache))
```

I've added `prn`S inside bb/add-record and all the values are non-`nil`, yet I still get the NPE.

Something subtle is going on here, and it's eluding me. Anyone have an idea?

Thanks inadvance.

EDIT: here's the full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:26)
    at sterling.bdbje$add_record.invoke(bdbje.clj:33)
    at sterling.loaders$load_subject_batch.invoke(loaders.clj:214)
    at sterling.loaders$load_subject_headings.invoke(loaders.clj:224)
    at sterling.loaders$_main.doInvoke(loaders.clj:257)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at sterling.loaders.main(Unknown Source)
```

As I said, this makes no sense to me, but is completely reproducible.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: I added the stacktrace to the original.

Comment: One of `k`, `v`, or `(:database dbm)` is nil. The line number from the stack trace should tell you which one.

Comment: Given the exception is coming from `invokeInstanceMethod` `(:database dbm)` is nil, but as I said in the question I added `prn` calls immediately before the call to `put` and *all* values are non-nil. That's why I don't understand what's going on! It doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It is indeed very strange from what you describe. What version of Clojure are you using?  Is there any way you can provide a self-contained example which shows the behavior and maybe put it up in a github repo?

Comment: Clojure 1.5.1. I ended up rewriting the utility in question in Java just so I could get my task done, so at this point making this work isn't a pressing issue. I'll see if I can get a slimmed down version that shows the problem though.